# How can i set a default country code on my Android application

Tags: java, android

I want to make a certain country code to becomes default but right now it comes in ascending order.

How can I achieve that?

Here is sample code:

```
 private void initViews() {

        registrationBean = new RegistrationBean();

        viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewflipper_registration);
        viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(0);

        llVerification = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_registration_mobile_otp);
        txtVerificationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_registration_mobile_otp_label);

        spinnerCountryCodes = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_registration_mobile_country_code);
        countryListBean = AppConstants.getCountryBean();
        Collections.sort(countryListBean.getCountries());
        List<String> countryDialCodes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (CountryBean bean : countryListBean.getCountries()) {
            countryDialCodes.add(bean.getDialCode());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the default country code in the list at the 0th index after for loop like:

```
for (CountryBean bean : countryListBean.getCountries()) {
    countryDialCodes.add(bean.getDialCode());
}
countryDialCodes.add(0, yourDefaultCountryCode);
```

Comment: thanks i need your help how can i make the country flag also default as the code